# Has Euler's Constant $\gamma$ been proven to be irrational?

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I found a paper by Kaida Shi called "[A Proof: Euler’s Constant γ is an Irrational Number](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0310/0310404.pdf)" which claims to have proven the irrationality of $\gamma$.

I know people have been trying to prove that $\gamma$ is irrational or not for hundreds of years.  I could not find very much on this paper online.  Does this paper in fact have a conclusive proof that $\gamma$ is irrational?

Comment: On the beginning of Page 6 it claims that the limit of rational numbers is rational. Well...

Comment: Looks like a word-document and not even latex. That's usually a sign to be extra careful.

Comment: Papers in arXiv are not refereed.

Comment: If you look at the other uploads of the same author, you see that he has also proven the Riemann hypothesis among many others. It's pretty obvious now.

Comment: @lhf: Correction for sake of someone who may get confused: Papers in arXiv are _not necessarily_ refeered. They may or may not be refereed. (E.g., papers that have been elsewhere refereed and submitted to a journal may still (and ideally will) be posted on the arXiv.)

Comment: To summarize all the above comments: **Be wary of things appearing in math.GM on arXiv.**

Comment: @abatkai: Alright! so $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, after all!

Comment: @ThomasE. Once I meet a guy who was very happy, he handed over a thick compendium written in word claiming $\pi=2.25$... :)

Comment: @AD.: These people must be the smartest MS word users on this planet. :-)

Comment: He has published his results in the Amazon Bookstore http://www.amazon.com/Proofs-Unsolved-Problems-Number-Theory/dp/3844316213

Comment: Finally got around to looking at your profile. Since I am nearly 50 years older perhaps you will forgive some advice. Rather than fool around with the likes of Kaida Shi, if you are seriously interested in proving Euler gamma irrational, look at the classic paper by Frits Beukers Bull London Math Soc 11 (1979) p268-272. It is an "Erdos Book version" of the proof that zeta(3) is irrational. The central problem with most things connected to the zeta function is figuring out a plan of attack. There are relatively few irrationality attacks. This one looks promising.

Comment: @Argon Sorry, that was aimed at Argon. I should have added that a pdf of the paper is available from scholar.google (always a good place to start looking for pdfs if you lack a high grade Athens password).

Comment: @user42362 I am not at all qualified to go trying to prove the irrationality of $\gamma$!  I was merely wondering why someone had published a paper with this claim, though I could not find any evidence to support this.

Comment: I think that if he defines $\theta=\alpha+\ln(2)$, then he gets $\theta-\beta=\frac{3}{4}$ and by the exactly the same argument he can prove that $\gamma$ is rational.. I guess this will come in the next paper...

Comment: Arxiv.org must delete this nonsense...

Comment: This person must be high on weeds all time...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, the paper is incorrect, and in many places. A quick way to check would be to see if it were published anywhere (it isn't). This isn't conclusive, but such a result would almost certainly be sent to some peer-reviewed journal.

I should also note some of the incredible things Kaida Shi has 'proven' in addition to Hilbert's 7th problem:

- Here's a [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309103) to his combined proofs of the Goldbach Conjecture, the Twin Primes Conjecture, and some parts of the vastly stronger Schinzel's hypothesis (which he doesn't mention in the abstract, but it nonetheless there).
- Here's a [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307136) to a geometric proof of the Riemann Hypothesis. But don't get too excited, because...
- Here's a [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308001) to a geometric proof of the generalized Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: Can I get excited on that last one?

Comment: Absolutely. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: *clears throat* $$\Large\textbf{OMGOMGOMOGMOGMOMG!!11}$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm not sure you will know this one. A soccer announcer in Spanish, named Andres Cantor, became famous for his exceptionally loud and long shout of GOL!. I tried to time some of them, I think one went to 20 seconds, which is very difficult, I tried it myself. They made a TV commercial with him announcing a chess match, with the players being able to hear him... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9s_Cantor

Comment: @Asaf   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUTzrMZVAAw and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O06Zp3gCT3c

Comment: He also claims a geometric proof of [Fermat's last theorem](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0309/0309005.pdf)

Comment: **PUBLISHED????** [in a book!?](http://www.bod.de/index.php?id=296&objk_id=510518)

Comment: He missed the Grand Riemann hypothesis.....

Answer (score 19):

@Argon. Shi starts out fine - looking at the 1/x curve, which is the obvious thing to try first. Before delving into the detail there notice the section heading of 3.2 "The proof ... ". Read that. He claims to have established various relationships between alpha, beta, gamma etc. It is obviously true that if S_1 = 1/2 - alpha, gamma=1-S_1, and alpha is irrational, then gamma is irrational. His argument is that alpha, beta are both rational or both irrational, but they cannot both be rational because their difference is 3/4 - ln 2, known to be irrational. That is all fine.

Indeed, the worrying part is that it is totally trite. It is spelt out at far too much length. But still. Why does he think alpha and beta are both rational or both irrational? That is spelt out in 3.1. He gives them as limits. The two expressions are set out at the bottom of page 5, top of page 6.

Beware \Lambda is not some strange constant, it is a coding glitch and seems to mean ... [ie dots]. He has a divergent series of terms which are roughly 1/n and is subtracting ln n to get something which tends to a finite limit. The series for alpha and beta differ only in that the alpha one has an extra term at the start and the beta one an extra term at the end so if you subtract 3/4 from alpha they line up. Similarly, the ln terms differ essentially by ln 2. So it looks as though he is right about their difference.

But the main point is why does he think they are both rational or both irrational? He has several pages deriving his limit expressions (which I have not bothered to do more than skim). But only a few sentences on how they help him:

"the series part of both series [sic] alpha_n and beta_n differ only a rational fraction, and the logarithm parts of both series [sic] alpha_n and beta_n have the identical attributes too. Therefore alpha_n and beta_n have the identical attributes too. Therefore, alpha_n and beta_n have identical attributes. Because alpha=lim alpha_n [expression given] and beta = lim beta_n [expression given] therefore both both series [sic] alpha and beta have identical attribute too. Namely, they are identically rational numbers or irrational numbers."

The bad English does not help, but does not seem to be the problem. Suppose for example we slightly garbled his expressions and made them alpha = lim(3/4 + 1/1+...+1/n - ln n) and beta = lim(1/1+...+1/n - ln n + ln 2). All his comments would still apply, but all he would have is alpha=gamma, beta=gamma+3/4-ln 2. Now why does he think that gamma is irrational iff gamma - ln 2 is irrational?

That is a ludicrous statement without further explanation. His argument boils down to:

1. gamma is irrational iff gamma-ln 2 is irrational.
2. gamma and gamma-ln 2 cannot both be rational because then ln 2 would be rational, whereas it is known to be irrational
3. Therefore gamma is irrational.

This would prove every number irrational. Without more the fact that X-Y and Y are irrational tells you nothing about whether X is irrational. Indeed it is always the case (as he uses in 2.) that if X is rational and Y is irrational then X-Y is irrational.

We all do stupid things but this paper is so incredibly stupid that part of me wonders whether it is a magnificent hoax. According to Wikipedia, Zhejiang Ocean University exists, so if it is a hoax he has covered the obvious bases. But these days many university maths departments are useless. Sadly there are plenty of people churning out junk, although most are sensible enough not to claim to have solved notorious long-standing problems.